# jsPanel, layout glicthes when resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, jpanel

Hope youre having a great weekend!

I am experimenting with jsPanel and just installed it. Now when i press a button, a new Panel will appear. So far so good but when tryign to resize it in the corner, the layout glichtes. The shadow of the Panel disappears and the header becomes huge!

In addition their docu says i can use bootstrap themes in the jsPanel options. It was working with "primary" and i replaced it with "dark" but its not working?

Any idea whats happening and why?

[image: Shows the apeparing panel]
[image: Shows the glitch]

MY HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>#</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- jsPanel CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jspanel4@4.3.0/dist/jspanel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- jsPanel JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jspanel4@4.3.0/dist/jspanel.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
34324
<div class="row fixed-bottom m-3 d-flex">
    <div class="col-lg-2">3</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">1</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">2</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex">
        <div class="card text-center">
            <div class="card-header">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">User</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link  active" href="#">Channel</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Recent</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                <button id="new_panel" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/panels.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My panels.js

```
$(function(){
    $( "#new_panel" ).on( "click", function() {
        jsPanel.create({
            theme:       'dark',
            headerTitle: 'my panel #1',
            position:    'center-top 0 58',
            contentSize: '450 250',
            content:     '<p>Example panel ...</p>',
            callback: function () {
                this.content.style.padding = '20px';
            },
        });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing immediately shows up: You load ***jspanel.js*** two times. First in the `<head>` via jsdelivr and once more at the end of the `<body>` element. I suggest to load the css in `<head>` and the js at the end of `<body>`. But only once please!

**Bootstrap themes and jspanel:** As noted in the [jsPanel docs](https://jspanel.de/api.html#options/theme/bs-themes) you have to prefix a bootstrap theme with `bootstrap-`. So in order to use the bootstrap dark theme you have to use option theme with the value `"bootstrap-dark"`.

`jsPanel.create({
    theme: 'bootstrap-dark'
});`

Fix those two issues first and see what happens ...